# How are self-extracting executables made?

Tags: executable, extract

There are many programs out there that will allow you to pack a few files together and generate an executable that has the necessary code to extract them. Somehow, those files are residing inside the executable. I am interested in doing the same thing; how is this done?

FYI, I'm interested primarily in Windows .exe files, if it makes a difference.

Comment: a "how-stuff-works" tag?

Comment: Yeah, if I know how it's done (or how it works), then I can do it.

Comment: @Mitch: How-stuff-works has been used over 30 times already, it's no C++ tag, but someone's gonna be getting the taxonomist badge for it.

Comment: Not anymore, it's getting [burninated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 1):

You could probably save a file/files in a resource, compile it into the exe then use some code in the exe to extract it out to a file.

ie:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/binaryresources.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Self extracting .exe files are usually archive files (zip, rar, tar, etc) concatenated together with a small program that does the extraction then executes the program that was extracted from the archive.

A really sophisticated one could extract the archive into memory and then jump to the extracted code and run it, but back in the old days, that sort of thing was easier to do.

If you wanted to write your own in Windows, you would create a small console application that did the extraction, and you would include the 'real' program in the console programs' resources.

Comment: Are these archive files just appended to the 'real' program that does the extraction?

Comment: In the olden days yes, now I think you get into trouble with virus scanners if your archive isn't accounted for in the exe header.

Answer (score 0):

There are also products like `pkzip` and [`winzip`](http://www.winzip.com/index.htm) which do it for you.  If your time is worth anything, those would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

[UPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPX) is a well known packer for Windows .EXE which can be found here on WikiPedia. And here is the main site on [sourceforge](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) for UPX.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.